# Google Maps Listener Context

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, scope

I need a Google Maps Marker to respond to an event triggered by the Map (idle). The event triggers a function. This function is SUPPOSED to act on the Marker, but of course, "this" refers to the map. How, inside the function, can I reference the Marker that set the event listener.

Every Marker will add an idle listener to the map. I could track all the markers, and upon a Map Idle Event, loop through them and trigger the function, but I was hoping on a more zen method.

My current method is this:

```
var self=newMarker;
google.maps.event.addListener(window.gmap,'idle',function(){
    self.setVisible(false); });
```

But it only seems to work for 1 marker. "newMarker" is the marker object I'm trying to access from inside the event, and as I said there's multiple markers, so I can't just store it in a global variable or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's "proxy", [jQuery Proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 basic options for you:

1 - Create an `Array` of the markers, implement one `function` that gets passed to `addListener`, and then loop through the markers when the event fires the function callback:

```
var markerList = new Array();
//build the markers and add them to markerList with multiple calls to push...
google.maps.event.addListener( window.gmap, "idle", function() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < markerList.length; i++ ) {
        markerList[i].setVisible( false );
    }
});
```

2 - Add a new callback function to the `google.maps.Marker.prototype` and make multiple calls to `addListener`, so that each marker receives its own event notification:

```
google.maps.Marker.prototype.idleCallback = function() {
    this.setVisible( false );
};

var newMarker1 = new google.maps.Marker( opts1 );
google.maps.event.addListener( window.gmap, "idle", newMarker1.idleCallback );
var newMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker( opts2 );
google.maps.event.addListener( window.gmap, "idle", newMarker2.idleCallback );
//and repeat for each marker; you get the idea
```

Myself, I always go with option 1 and I'm sticking with that approach. I worry that attaching many listeners to the Map will drag down performance. Plus, it involves mucking around in the google code prototype.

But this is an interesting idea. If you give something like this a go, please let me know how it performs and how it worked out for you.

Comment: Solution 1 won't work for me, I'm attempting to avoid JS looping in this application.